# Getting invalid connection with Perl and DBI

Tags: sql-server, perl, dbi

I am trying to connect to MS SQL Server with Perl with the following code:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server}; 
                         Server=$host_name; 
                         UID=$user_name;
                         PWD=$password") || 
die "Cannot connect to $host_name $user_name: $DBI::errstr";
```

After 15 seconds it comes back with:

> DBI connect('Driver={SQL Server}; Server=myserver.mydomain.org; UID=username; PWD=passwd','',...) failed: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]Invalid connection. (SQL-08001) [state was 08001 now 01000]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Invalid Instance()). (SQL-01000) at ./copy_hp_data.pl line 81.

I can connect to this server fine though SSMS, and I added the hostname to the ODBC data sources (32/64 bit ODBC Drive 11 for SQL Server).

I searched the archives and tried many of the solutions but am at a loss.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354957) from a couple of days ago. The problem was whitespace between the parts of the DSN. Also, canonical `DBI->connect` call has the userid and password as separate arguments.

Comment: @mob As I [commented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354957/perl-dbi-remote-connection#comment52586921_32354957) on that question, I highly doubt whitespace in the DSN was a problem, and the OP never clarified what they changed to make it work. That was a different driver, though, so who knows.

Comment: Are named pipes and TCP/IP [enabled as protocols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181035.aspx) on the server? Do you happen to have the SQL Server Native Client ODBC driver installed? That's what we use at `$work`, and I've not seen this error message before.

Comment: @mob I tried changing to this:

      my $dsn = "dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$host_name;Database=$db_name";
   my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user_name, $password, { RaiseError => 1 });

And I got the same error.